# Intel math library

Tags: math, intel

I've just installed Intel PS,XE 2011 Extreme Edition after completing my code hoping Intel compiler would be faster for an Intel processor. I am interested in math functions currently but I am confused with the abundant number of libraries. Even I googled dot product but havent obtained anything useful. Could you direct me to a library and functions for vector operations like dot, vector product... Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the [MKL Users Guide](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-documentation/).  The dot product a BLAS function, which is provided in MKL under the name `cblas_*dot` (C) or `*dot` (FORTRAN), where `*` is a letter indicating the type of the vectors being operated on.

Comment: I took a look at MKL Users Guide. Here I am confused with BLAS, CBLAS, LAPACK, Vector Math Functions or Statistical ones... Don't you know a simple site explaining those functions for dummies.